# Remove multiple extensions from all files in a directory (Bash)

Tags: bash, file-rename

Thanks to messing up my first attempts to do this, I now have a directory full of files that are now named like this:

```
valery-special-music-poetry.txt.mtxt.md.md.txt.mtxt.md.md.md
```

which I need to be named:

```
valery-special-music-poetry.md
```

how can I do this from the command line?

I am running: GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin12)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help you

```
#!/bin/bash
for filename in *
do
    x=`echo $filename | sed 's/\..*\./\./g'`
    mv $filename $x
done
```

Save this to a file called rename.sh

```
chmod +x rename.sh
./rename.sh
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for file in *; do mv "$file" "${file/.*./.}"; done
```

Comment: Disclaimer: As usual, this will cause problems if your filenames contain spaces. See http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/handling-filenames-with-spaces-in-bash.html for workarounds

Answer (score 3):

By Shell itself:

```
for i in *; do mv "$i" "${i%%.*}.${i##*.}"; done
```

Unless your dir are single level, I suggest using find, if you have in Apple.

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -1 *.txt.mtxt.md.md.txt.mtxt.md.md.md | nawk -F"." '{cmd="mv "$0" "$1".md";system(cmd)}'
```

Comment: I think awk -vFS=".txt" will be safer